# How do I remove the top margin in a web page?

Tags: html, css

I have had this problem with every web page I have created.  There is always a top margin above the 'main container' div I use to place my content in the center of the page.  I am using a css style sheet and have set margins and padding in the body to 0px and set the margin and padding to 0 in the div:

```
body{
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    color: black; 
    font-size: 10pt; 
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}

div.mainContainer{
    height: auto; 
    width: 68em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have looked online many times, but all I can see to do is set these margin and padding attributes.  Is there something else I should be doing?  The margin exists in IE and Firefox.

Here is a more thorough look at the code (it is in the beginning stages of creation, so there isn't much in it...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
        <title></title>
        <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
        <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" --><!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
        <link href="../Styles/KB_styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mainContainer">
            <p>Here is the information</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    color: black; 
    font-size: 10pt; 
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}

/* ---Section Dividers --------------------------------------------------------------*/
div.mainContainer{
    position: relative; 
    height: auto; 
    width: 68em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0;
}

div.header{
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

div.leftSidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 22%; 
    height: 40em;
    margin: 0;
}

div.mainContent{
    margin-left: 25%;
}

div.footer{
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 0em; 
    margin: 0;
}

/* Hide from IE5-mac. Only IE-win sees this. \*/
   * html div.leftSidebar { margin-right: 5px; }
   * html div.mainContent {height: 1%; margin-left: 0;}
/* End hide from IE5/mac */
```

Comment: I don't see anything odd. Can you please repost this as an SSCCE? http://sscce.org, from `<doctype>` and `<html>` until with `</html>` with the *minimum* required stylesheet to reproduce the same problem in the `<style>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think I found the problem.  The paragraph margins seemed to be transferring up to the div.  When I added p{margin: 0;} to the css the problem dissappeared.

Comment: @RoryG, please post your solution as an answer below and accept your own answer.  As you can see it would be most helpful to people still trying to answer your original question.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I had similar problem, got this resolved by the following CSS:

```
body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 116):

Is your first element `h1` or similar?  That element's `margin-top` could be causing what seems like a margin on `body`.

Comment: You nailed it, this was also my problem and in this case using important! like suggested in the accepted answer doesn't solve it (and based on the comments by the guy who posted the question this was also *his* problem but with a <p> tag instead of <h1>).

Comment: On inspecting web page in chrome, that margin appeared outside the body, but there was a sub component (angular) inside body which was using `<p></p>` tag on the top which was indeed causing the issue. Chrome inspecting tool can't be trusted blindly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spent the past several hours scratching my head at this one. I'd give you 100 upvotes if I could!

Answer (score 42):

The best way to reset margins for all elements is to use the css asterisk rule.

Add this to the top of your css under the @charset:

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

This will take away all the preset margins and padding with all elements body,h1,h2,p,etc.
Now you can make the top or header of your page flush with the browser along with any images or text in other divs.

Comment: It's better to adjust the proper tag, like <p> or <h2>, instead of walking around the problem, causing many other problems on the way.

Comment: This is the solution for me. Weird thing is that the HTML begins with html and body tag. They give the white space at the top. Specifying html and body as padding/marging: 0. does not help. But the asterix does. While I can't find any other tag at the top.

Answer (score 17):

A lot of elements in CSS have default padding and margins set on them. So, when you start building a new site, it's always good to have a `reset.css` file ready. Add this to make to rub the default values, so you have more control over your web page.

```
/* CSS reset */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


/* Extra options you might want to consider*/

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
input{
    border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
    padding:3px 5px 4px;
    color:#979797;
    width:190px;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { 
    border:0;
}
```

I hope this helps all fellow developers this is something that bugged for me a while when I was learning.

Comment: html {margin: 0px;} solves the problem (which was how to remove the html margin). You da man.

Comment: nice solution .

Answer (score 9):

You can prevent the effects of [margin collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) with:

```
body { overflow: hidden }
```

That will make the `body` margins remain accurate.

Comment: Yes this is almost certainly a collapsing margin issue.  Setting margin:0 !important is not going to help.  However setting body {overflow:auto} will fix it without any negative impact.  This should be marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem. It was resolved by following css line;

```
h1{margin-top:0px}
```

My main div contained `h1` tag in the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Try margin ***-10px***:

```
body { margin-top:-10px; }
```

Comment: This one worked 4 me, the other suggestions didn't ... weird cannot see why

Comment: This is bad practice. I wrote this years ago when I didn't know web dev well. Finding the source of the problem is much better than just hiding it.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having a similar issue. I wanted a percentage height and top-margin for my container div, but the body would take on the margin of the container div. 
I think I figured out a solution.

Here is my original (problem) code:

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    height:100%;                    
    margin-top:0%;
    padding:0%; 
}

#pageContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:96%;                  /* 100% - (margin * 2) */
    height:96%;                 /* 100% - (margin * 2) */           
    margin:2% auto 0% auto;
    padding:0%;
}
```

My solution was to set the height of the body the same as the height of the container.
    html {
        height:100%;
    }

```
body {
    height:96%;     /* 100% * (pageContainer*2) */
    margin-top:0%;
    padding:0%; 
}

#pageContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:96%;                  /* 100% - (margin * 2) */
    height:96%;                 /* 100% - (margin * 2) */           
    margin:2% auto 0% auto;
    padding:0%;
}
```

I haven't tested it in every browser, but this seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue has been driving me crazy for several hours. What I found and you may want to check is html encoding. In my html file I declared utf-8 encoding and used Notepad++ to enter html code in utf-8 format. What I DID forget of was UTF-8 BOM and No BOM difference. It seems when utf-8 declared html file is written as UTF-8 BOM there is some invisible extra character at the begining of the file. The character (non-printable I guess) effects in one row of "text" at the top of the rendered page. And you cannot see the difference in source-view of the browser (Chrome in my case). Both nice and spoiled files seem identical to the very character, still one of them renders nicely and the other one shows this freaking upper margin.

To wrap it up the solution is to convert the file to UTF-8 NO BOM and one can do it in i.e. Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that everyone was asking for -- its at the very beginning of development so there isn't much in it yet, which may be helpful...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
        <title></title>
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" --><!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <link href="../Styles/KB_styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="header">  </div>
  <div class="mainContent">  </div>
 <div class="footer">  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    color: black; font-size: 10pt; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;}

html{padding: 0; margin: 0;}

/* ---Section Dividers -----------------------------------------------*/
div.mainContainer{
    height: auto; width: 68em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;}

div.header{padding: 0; margin-bottom: 1em;}

div.leftSidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 22%; height: 40em;
    margin: 0;}

div.mainContent{margin-left: 25%;}

div.footer{
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 0em; margin: 0;}

/* Hide from IE5-mac. Only IE-win sees this. \*/
* html div.leftSidebar { margin-right: 5px; }
* html div.mainContent {height: 1%; margin-left: 0;}
/* End hide from IE5/mac */
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce problem in any browser.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about where to put this.  I didn't know what to do.  I will add it now.

Answer (score 1):

For opera just add this in header

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='handheld' href='body.css' />
```

This makes opera use most of your customised css.

Answer (score 1):

It is a `<p>` element that creates the top margin. You removed all top margins except of that element.

Answer (score 1):

same problem, h1 was causing it to have that massive margin-top. after that you can use body{margin: 0;} and its looks good. another way is using *{margin: 0;} but it might mess up margins of other elements for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.  For me, this was the only thing that worked:

```
div.mainContainer { padding-top: 1px; }
```

It actually works with any number that's not zero.  I really have no idea why this took care of it.  I'm not that knowledgeable about CSS and HTML and it seems counterintuitive. Setting the `body, html, h1` margins and paddings to 0 had no effect for me.  I also had an `h1` at the top of my page

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<span>Example</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also check if:

```
{float: left;}
```

and

```
{clear: both;}
```

are used correctly in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you have a h1 element with a margin or padding of greater than 0, you want the wrapping element to have the style: overflow:hidden. Sometimes, applying it to the body won't work, as the element containing the h1 or p element may be a div.

The wrapping element could be main, div or something else.

So don't do this:

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

And hover every element like a h1 or p with a default margin, and then check the immediate parent and then apply a overflow:hidden on that element.

Answer (score -1):

```
style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;" cz-shortcut-listen="true"
```

paste this at your body tag!

this will remove the top margin