# How to remove the margin at the top of my page

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to delete the margin top of my page. I will show you what I mean with a screenshot[image]

You can see in my pic there are a red arrow that indicate my problem. How I can delete this margin?
I post here my css:

```
div#header {
    background-color: #6495ED;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, black, gray);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(gray), to(black));
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:  sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

li {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

So any suggestion about how I can delete this margin just above my header?

Here you can see my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>  
        <title>Lista coupon</title>
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/memoria.js"          type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style  src="../css/style.css"          type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadJson();">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Lista coupon salvati</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Di seguito trovi tutte le promozioni salvate</p>
            <div id="list">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your HTML code?

Comment: can you send html code

Comment: I will post my html, sorry

Comment: Please see my comment in similar thread <http://stackoverflow.com/a/32968720/5413693>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `margin: 0;` to `<h1>` element

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5w6Es/

Same problem as with the `margin-left` of `<ul>` elements, or `margin-top` / `margin-bottom` of `<p>` elements, etc.

You need to reset their default styles when using them at the borders of your page.

Comment: Your solution works better than other I will use yours thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try removing padding and margin also for the `html` element, (not only the `body`)

Try also to remove the default margin (differently) applied by every browser to the `h1` element that you didn't redefined/reset and which is probably [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) over the `#header` element

```
html {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
}

h1 {
   ...
   margin: 0;  
}
```

Comment: fill a fiddle reproducing the problem, with your real markup. anyway this really seems a problem related to collapsing margin of your main title: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: `+1` Without a CSS nuller, headings have by default a margin, setting it to '0' is the correct way to go. Tested and (of course) works.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you. the problem here is also due to the margin that is applied not the title but apparently applied to the parent container. That's why an *easy-n-dirty* solution is to apply a negative margin to the header as suggested below. But I wouldn't never recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add margin:0px; to this CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/vv6DL/

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:  sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what browsers its occuring in.

If you use Firebug and its tools you should be able to see what is causing the spacing and then set that to zero, however, a "cheat" would be to use a reset css script such as Meyers http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ to clean up all those browser inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm using Firefox (Gecko engine) and Chrome/Safari (WebKit)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
h1
{
     margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is by adding the **:first-child** pseudo-element in your css to your first element such as `<h1> or <ul>` etc etc within your body-element.

So an example using your mark up above would be

```
h1:first-child { margin-top: 0; }
```

This eliminates interfering with all further `<h1>` elements in your code and also without needless css classes added to your html mark-up.

I hope this helps as I was having the sam problem with little luck with the answers provided.