# What's the most effective way to use multiple background colors for the entire page?

Tags: css, html, background

I am attempting to create multi color backgrounds.

I want the entire background to be blue with red sections in certain containers. I want the red to go all the way from side to side of the page without any white spaces that may be rendered by the browser. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="Blue">
   Here is one color
</div>

<div class="Red">
    Here is one color
</div>

<div class="Blue">
    Here is one color
</div>

<div class="Red">
    Here is one color
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Blue {
    width:100%; /* I want the width of the background to be 100% of the page ?*/
    height: 30%; /* I want the height of the background container to be 30% of the page? */
    background-color: blue;
}
.Red {
    width:100%;
    height: 30%; /*The next 30% of the page ? */
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4DXDX/ The edges are offset with a white margin on the sides.

How do I get the color to go all the way from edge to edge? Is putting the appropriate colors in a div tag the right/ or efficient way to do this?

Below is an image of the background i want to create.

[image]

Comment: google for css reset (or normalize) ... or take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99643/css-reset-default-styles-for-common-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS rule:

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

This will get rid of the margin. http://jsfiddle.net/TZRhn/

Also, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489070/how-do-i-remove-the-top-margin-in-a-web-page) for more details.

In the comment @Kheema mentioned that universal selector may be a bad idea. You can use `reset.css` instead.

Check more of discussions of `reset.css` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do)

Comment: I am not really fan of using `Universal Selector` ideally you should use `reset.css`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `margin` and `padding` from the page. And the easiest way is to remove padding and margin by using this style.

```
html, body{margin:0; padding:0}
```

**Note:** It would be a good practice to use the `reset.css` file to avoid this kind of weird problem.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

You have to add padding to the divs now if you dont want the contents of the div touching the edges